# Running java apps in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I am using ubuntu AIM on EC2.

I would like to run a java app (start it) and make sure it continues to run even after I log out from SSH (using putty).

How is that possible?

---

Follow up to Martin's answer:

1. Consider I use system.outprintln in the java program... Where will it be printed? Is there a way to tell the process to output it somewhere I can later find it?
2. How can I stop the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the bash command line

```
$ java -jar myapp.jar & disown
```

Comment: Thanks. Follow up: 1) consider I use system.outprintln in the java program... Where will it be printed? Is there a way to tell the process to output it somewhere I can later find it? 2) How can I stop the process?

Comment: Use java -jar myapp.jar > outfile & disown to capture output, and you can -- use the jps command to find the process and signal it with kill(1).